# Как в Twig создать переменную и присвоить ей значение из другой переменной?

Tags: twig

```
{% if mpn %} // если есть переменная
{{ mpn }} // то вывожу ее

{% set collectionname = '{{mpn}}' %} // и устанавливаю новую переменную, присвоив ей значение из переменной "{{ mpn }}"

коллекция - {{ collectionname }} - // но в итоге выводится не само значение, а голый прям текст - {{ mpn }}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, кто пришел сюда с таким же вопросом:

при установки переменой и присвоении ей значения из другой переменной нужно указывать переменную, от которой хотим получить значение. без кавычек и скобок

Неправильно:

```
{% set collectionname = '{{mpn}}' %}
```

Правильно:

```
{% set collectionname = mpn %}
```